# Does the Levenshtein (Edit Distance) algorithm perform faster than O(n*m) in a native graph database?

Tags: neo4j, time-complexity, graph-databases, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

Would the Levenshtein (Edit Distance) have better time complexity in a native graph database such as Neo4j than the current limit of O(n*m)? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [implementations](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/4.0/src/main/java/apoc/text/Strings.java) of `apoc.text.levenshteinDistance` and `apoc.text.levenshteinSimilarity` simply rely on [org.apache.commons.text.similarity.LevenshteinDistance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html) to do the calculation, the APOC library does not introduce any complexity improvements.

In any case, such a calculation should just compare 2 strings of text and should not in any way rely on the graphical nature of the DB.

And finally, [it has been proven](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014arXiv1412.0348B/abstract) that the complexity **cannot** be improved (unless the [Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) is wrong).